# The web-server device requires the Dart Debug Chrome extension for debugging

Tags: flutter, dart

i am  trying  to  run connected devices such as

```
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2295]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.180
```

but always when i choose to run on  web it always turn out to be like  this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             96.7s
Failed to launch browser after 3 tries. Command used to launch it: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
--user-data-dir=C:\Users\IRADUK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.50c80c25\flutter_tools_chrome_device.42e3d2fe --remote-debugging-port=49713    
--disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check
--disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://localhost:49615
Failed to launch browser. Make sure you are using an up-to-date Chrome or Edge. Otherwise, consider using -d web-server instead and filing an
issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

To fix this issue, i tried the following:

1. Make sure i are using an up-to-date version of Chrome.
2. Disable my firewall or antivirus program temporarily and try launching Chrome again.
3. Restart my computer and try launching Chrome again.
4. Make sure that i am running Chrome as an administrator.
5. Used the -d web-server flag to launch Chrome in web server mode.

> run -d chrome

```
The web-server device requires the Dart Debug Chrome extension for debugging. Consider using the Chrome or Edge devices for an improved
development workflow.
```

6. Used the -v flag to get more verbose output from Flutter.